# Is there a simple way to find all connected nodes using python?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

```
A = ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', 'node5'] #nodes
B = {'node1':'node2', 'node3':'node4', 'node4':'node5'} #connections

C = [['node1', 'node2'], ['node3', 'node4', 'node5']] #wanted result
```

I want to have all nodes that are connected to each other; I want to have C when the input is A,B.

```
def demo(A, B): 
    # code
    return C
```

I have tried complicated ways to get the wanted results but no success. I hope some one can help me with this.

Comment: You can do a DFS (Depth First Search) or BFS (Breadth First Search) on the nodes

Comment: Is it possible that ```node3``` is connected to ```node4, node5 and node6```? How will B look like then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

Just looping into the dictionary and converting the key-value pair into a list

And merging them in a separate loop

Code:

```py
B1 = {'node1':'node2', 'node3':'node4', 'node4':'node5'}
B2 = {'node1':'node2', 'node3':'node4', 'node4':'node5', 'node5':'node6'}

def nodes_to_list(_dict):
  res = sorted([[i, j] for i, j in _dict.items()])

  for index1, i in enumerate(res):
    for index2, j in enumerate(res):
      if index1 != index2:
        if any(a in j for a in i):
          res[index1] = sorted(set(i+j))
          del res[index2]
  return res

print(nodes_to_list(B1))
print(nodes_to_list(B2))
```

Outputs:

```py
[['node1', 'node2'], ['node3', 'node4', 'node5']]
[['node1', 'node2'], ['node3', 'node4', 'node5', 'node6']]
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: Actually when I add more nodes it's not working any more:

`A = ['node1', 'node2', 'node3', 'node4', 'node5', 'node6']`

`B = {'node1':'node2', 'node3':'node4', 'node4':'node5', 'node5':'node6' }`

>>`C = [['node3', 'node4', 'node5'], ['node4', 'node5', 'node6'], ['node1', 'node2'], ['node1', 'node2']]`

instead of `C = [['node3', 'node4', 'node5', 'node6'], ['node1', 'node2']]`
@Ghost

Comment: This will not work for all the cases

Comment: @KaziSohan i know, im still working on it

Comment: Is it possible that ```node3``` is connected to ```node4, node5 and node6```? How will B look like then?

Comment: @Prosti if it doesn’t work, you should uncheck it as “the answer”.

Comment: B would look like this >> B = {'node1':'node2', 'node3':'node4', 'node4':'node5', 'node5':'node6'}

Comment: @Prosti hey, i updated my code, check it and tell me whether its working or not

Answer (score 2):

networkx is an option:

```
import networkx as nx

# Initialize graph
G = nx.Graph()
# Put all your nodes into graph
G.add_nodes_from(A)
# Add edges to graph
for n1, n2 in B.items():
    G.add_edge(n1, n2)
# Create list of connected components of G
C = [list(c) for c in nx.connected_components(G)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
nodes = {'node1':'node2', 'node3':'node4', 'node4':'node5'}
def paths(n=None, c = []):
   if n is None:
      for a in nodes:
         if all(j != a for j in nodes.values()):
            yield from paths(a)
   elif n not in nodes:
      yield c+[n]
   else:
      yield from paths(nodes[n], c+[n])

print(list(paths()))
```

Output:

```
[['node1', 'node2'], ['node3', 'node4', 'node5']]
```

On a larger dictionary of nodes:

```
nodes = {'node1':'node2', 'node3':'node4', 'node4':'node5', 'node5':'node6' }
```

Output:

```
[['node1', 'node2'], ['node3', 'node4', 'node5', 'node6']]
```

Comment: Will vote for it - if there is some more details.  Pure code w/o any explanation won't help those beginners.